# Geddy + node.js + passport-facebook + cant get email profile fields

Tags: node.js, facebook-login, geddy, passport-facebook

i am using module for this
    "passport": "0.1.x",
    "passport-facebook": "0.1.x",

Showing profile output in console
 { provider: 'facebook',
   id: '100003558512345',
   username: 'testname',
   gender: 'male',
   **emails: [ { value: undefined } ]**
 }

Email filed value is undefined.

How to get value in email filed?

Answer (score 0):

user permission for emails 
eg. passport.authenticate(authType, { scope: ['email','user_birthday'] })

Email for facebook will come if and only if facebook user is email verified.